# PHPmailer sends emails to junk folder in outlook account

Tags: forms, outlook, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer on my website in order to send the user’s information to my outlook email. Everything looks fine about the email sending process, but the problem I’m facing is that all the information that user sends to me send to junk folder by outlook. This is my code :

```
<?php

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require_once('private/initialize.php');
    require_once('private/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php');
    require_once('private/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php');
    require_once('private/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php');

    // SERVER SIDE VALIDATION
    $errors = [];
    $user = [];
    $user['name'] = '';
    $user['email'] = '';
    $user['telephone'] = '';
    $user['address'] = '';
    $user['city'] = '';
    $user['date_time'] = '';
    $success = '';
    $failed = '';

    if (is_post_request()) {

        $user = [];
        $user['name'] = $_POST['name'] ? $_POST['name'] : '';
        $user['email'] = $_POST['email'] ? $_POST['email'] : '';
        $user['telephone'] = $_POST['telephone'] ? $_POST['telephone'] : '';
        $user['address'] = $_POST['address'] ? $_POST['address'] : '';
        $user['city'] = $_POST['city'] ? $_POST['city'] : '';
        $user['date_time'] = $_POST['date_time'] ? $_POST['date_time'] : '';

        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

        $email_body = "I hope it worked";
        $user_email = $user['name'];

        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->Host = "smtp-mail.outlook.com";
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Username = 'example@outlook.com';
        $mail->Password = '*********';

        // Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($user['email'], $user['name']);
        $mail->addAddress('example@outlook.com', 'My name');
        $mail->addReplyTo($user['email'], $user['name']);

        // Content
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject = $user_email;
        $mail->Body = $email_body;

        if (!$mail->send()) {
           $failed = "<div class='failed-message'>The email was not sent!</div>";
        } else {
           $success = "<div class='success-message'>Tack " . $user['name'] . " för din bokining. Vi återkommer snart.</div>";
           $user = [];
           $user['name'] = '';
           $user['email'] = '';
           $user['telephone'] = '';
           $user['address'] = '';
           $user['city'] = '';
           $user['date_time'] = '';
        }

    }

    else {
        $user = [];
        $user['name'] = '';
        $user['email'] = '';
        $user['telephone'] = '';
        $user['address'] = '';
        $user['city'] = '';
        $user['date_time'] = '';
    }

?>
```

I tried many solutions, but none of them is working, so please tell me what should I do to solve this problem. Thanks